# error al instalar el JDK en windows 10 de 64

Tags: java, windows10

Tengo un problema al instalar el JDK `jdk-8u111-nb-8_2-windows-x64`, el programa se ejecuta y se cierra y crea un archivo log, `hs_err_pid14104.log` con la siguiente información:

Agradezco su ayuda

[hs_err_pid14104](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14UUW-tFik5XmQi2V3QmR1zWcvE-TIwyU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Según he revisado, parece el error suele suceder si tienes activado el [`GodMode`](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-god-mode-windows-10) en Windows 10. Para solucionarlo tienes 2 opciones según la comunidad:

Opción 1: Revisa tú versión `Build` con este comando de PowerShell `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version` y si estas en la versión `build 1703` o similar debes de actualizar el sistema operativo para que instale una `build` mas reciente, porque en la build 1703 se activo este modo por defecto para algunas PC.

Opción 2: Si tienes constancia de haber realizo este proceso, debes de eliminar la carpeta que esta en [`GodMode`](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-god-mode-windows-10) .